# general plotting/graph questions related to legend positions and text size

Tags: plotting, legending, text

I have the following MWE

```
Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["frequency", Medium], 
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(v\), \(mean\)]\)", Medium]}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"asd"}],
 ListPlot[{{0.5, 0.25}, {1, 0.5}}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLegends -> {"asd"}]]
```

There are several things I am trying to do, which I can't get to work. I will list them here

1. How can I make the two legends be inside the graph, not outside?
2. How can I make the legends be aligned over/under eachother, exactly? Now the are aligned to the left.
3. I am really interested in finding a way to alter the size of the `FrameLabel`, ticks and legends in a easy way. So far I have only been able to do it by using `Small`, `Medium` and `Large`, but that is not very dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easier to put this type of legend together by hand, as follows:

```
Legended[
  Show[ (* fill in with plots without PlotLegends option *) ],
  LineLegend[{ColorData[1][1], Red}, {"asd", "asd"}, Joined -> {True, False}]
]
```

[image]

The disadvantage is you lose the automatic color generation, but you gain control and it is automatically formatted as you would like.  The next step is to place it where you want it, and you do that using `Placed`. For this, I would use either

```
Placed[legend, {Right, Center}] (* or, Top, Bottom, or Left with Center *)
```

or

```
Placed[legend, Scaled[{0.5, 0.9}]
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Lets start with assumption that We do not want to create legend from the beginning. You can put `PlotLabel` inside using `Placed` and allign content with 3rd argument of `Placed`.

```
Show[{
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["frequency", Medium], 
     Style["v", Medium]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{"asd"}, {Right, Center}, 
     Pane[#, 60, Alignment -> Center] &]]
  ,
  ListPlot[{{0.5, 0.25}, {1, 0.5}}, PlotStyle -> Red,
   PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[{"asd"}, {Right, Center}, 
       Pane[#, 60, Alignment -> Center] &] ]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

I'm not going to describe creating new legend because of rcollyer answer  :)
And as He has said, each method has adventages and disadventages. Honestly, his is more convenient for me.